# How to apply a new function to all records automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

My Odoo 11 system already has records created by users. When I create a new function to add new features to odoo application, the function only applies to new records created after the existence of the new function. To apply it to existing records, I must edit each old record,change the value of one the fields used by the function, and save.

My question: is there a way for a new function created in the python source to apply to all records automatically without needing to edit and save each old record?

Comment: I think for the first time it will do like you said i.e. will edit and save the old records too, but next time you it will apply to all records.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use ODOO (API) a simple script that do this can do the trick :

1. connect to your server.
2. search for all records.
3. call the method for those IDs.

Get all the `IDs` of you database:

```
  ids  = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'your.model.name', 'search',[[]])
```

Then call that method:

```
   models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'your.model.name', 'your_method_name', [ids])
```